# How to re-open a rejected PR on Github

Tags: git, github

I just created a PR on Github, and it got rejected and closed.

Now I left a new comment and I want to re-open it.

How should I do that? And is it even possible?

Comment: If you've left a comment, you'll need to give the maintainers time to review it. You _could_ create a new PR with the same changes, but that's not likely to set up a productive relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be a maintainer to do so. Add a comment and a maintainer might reopen it (usually depending on the contribution guidelines of the repo), otherwise resubmit it.

Answer (score 2):

You are apparently talking about https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/37237 which proposes the addition of a new API to the stable, published branch of a popular framework.

[The maintainer's comment when closing](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/37237#issuecomment-831419387) explains, in somewhat rough terms, why they closed this PR. ("Turn ... into a *college*"? I guess they mean *collection?)*
They seem to be saying that the workaround is simple enough that adding new code is not worth the effort.

While it would have been helpful if the maintainer had explained in more detail why they closed the PR, my speculation is that they do this a lot, but not enough to create a boilerplate to explain why. In this situation, my intuition would be to advise you to take a good look at their [contribution guideline](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/contributions) for an explanation; in particular, [the *Which Branch?* section](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/contributions#which-branch) directs you to a Discord channel to discuss further if it's unclear which branch to target. While your proposed change doesn't break backwards compatibility (and as such would be suitable for 8.X if I understand their organization correctly), it introduces new behavior which might be more suitable for a future major release. Either way, perhaps a change like this should be brought up on their [Issue Board](https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues), or at least discussed in the Discord channel, before plunging ahead with a PR.

Bottom line, probably do what you can to figure out why it was closed before you request reopening.